# Swift - Parse certain data

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing

Need to extract the data of `desc` from the below API response. From that i need to extract every `a` and `b`, so that i can use that in for a math addition app.

```
data from the server

 [
    {
        "id": 226,
        "name": "chorename",
        "desc": "{\n  \"questions\" : [\n    {\n      \"b\" : 2,\n      \"a\" : 1\n    },\n    {\n      \"b\" : 3,\n      \"a\" : 2\n    },\n    {\n      \"b\" : 2,\n      \"a\" : 8\n    },\n    {\n      \"b\" : 9,\n      \"a\" : 7\n    },\n    {\n      \"b\" : 3,\n      \"a\" : 6\n    }\n  ],\n  \"operation\" : \"addition\"\n}",
        "reward": "1.00",
        "sched": "2018-04-19T15:54:24.657644+08:00",
        "parent": "shit",
        "type": "homework",
        "child": "",
        "occurrence": {
            "name": "once"
        },
        "status": {
            "name": "ongoing"
        },
        "date_created": "2018-04-23T14:16:35.739436+08:00",
        "date_modified": "2018-04-23T14:16:35.790237+08:00"
    }
]
code on getting request
func demoApi1() {
        Alamofire.request("", method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in

            switch(response.result) {
            case .success(_):
                guard let json = response.result.value as! [[String:Any]]? else{ return}
                print("Ang Response: , \(json)")

                for item in json {

                    var a = self.getAllDetail.append(item )
                    print("shit:" , a)


                    // if let title = item["title"] as? String {
                    //   self.titleArray.append(title)
                    // }

                }
                if !self.getAllDetail.isEmpty{
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {

                    }
                }
                break

            case .failure(_):
                print("Error")
                break

            }
        }

    }

let devices = assign "a" here
        let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(devices.count)))
        let randomItem = devices[randomIndex]
        print("random item:" ,randomItem)


        let device2 = //assign "b" here
        let randomIndex1 = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(devices.count)))
        let randomItem1 = device2[randomIndex]
```

**API Response:**

```
 Ang Response [["status": {
    name = ongoing;
}, "sched": 2018-04-10T14:22:00+08:00, "desc": asdasdasdsa, "id": 224, "reward": 1.00, "parent": das, "child": dasdas, "date_created": 2018-04-19T15:54:24.657644+08:00, "name": sad, "occurrence": {
    name = once;
}, "type": , "date_modified": 2018-04-19T15:54:24.703520+08:00], ["status": {
    name = ongoing;
}, "sched": 2018-04-19T15:54:24.657644+08:00, "desc": {
  "questions" : [
    {
      "b" : 2,
      "a" : 1
    },
    {
      "b" : 3,
      "a" : 2
    },
    {
      "b" : 2,
      "a" : 8
    },
    {
      "b" : 9,
      "a" : 7
    },
    {
      "b" : 3,
      "a" : 6
    }
  ],
  "operation" : "addition"
}, "id": 226, "reward": 1.00, "parent": shit, "child": , "date_created": 2018-04-23T14:16:35.739436+08:00, "name": chorename, "occurrence": {
    name = once;
}, "type": homework, "date_modified": 2018-04-23T14:16:35.790237+08:00]]
```

Comment: You want to extract the data of desc right.?

Comment: yeah Sir , cause the data from desc are the choices for the app

Comment: choice a + choice b

Comment: i wanted to assign every choice "a" to let devices  and then randomize it

Comment: Added the answer

Comment: do u want to know how i pull the data?

Comment: the best thing would be if you can share the WS you used so that i can make a demo for you

Comment: i will update the question

Comment: i have update it

Comment: @DurnKurvirck value of desc is not a string. It is already a dictionary. Desc contains "questions" array and "operation" string values

Comment: This response is more confusing than the raw JSON. This is most likely not the real response.

Comment: i could provide the could in pulling it if you want to know

Comment: the first one is the raw format from the server the ang response if the response i got using alamofire

Comment: @DurnKuvrick Join the chat so that we can debug that https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169569/abhirajsinh-and-durn

Comment: i cant reply low repu

Comment: @AkornDurnKurvirck Could you paste your response in json format? Its not clear enough to read as it is.

Comment: Even if you manage to parse this to an `[[String:Any]]?` (and I heavily doubt you will manage to just cast `response.result.value` into that) you will end up with an incredible optional interpretation nightmare. Take the time to learn about the `Codable` protocol, define an appropriate `struct` to handle your date and use `JSONDecoder().decode(...)` to get the right thing in the first place. You will still have to iterate through your `questions` in order to get `a` and `b`, but that is going to be it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code can be used to convert a `json string` from `string` to `dictionary`

**Objective-c**

```
+ (NSDictionary *)dictionaryFromJSONString:(NSString *)jsonString
{
    // @"{\"2\":\"3\"}"
    NSError *jsonError;
    NSData *objectData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:objectData
                                                         options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                           error:&jsonError];
    return json;
}
```

**SWIFT**

```
func getDictionaryFromString(_ jsonString: String) -> [String:Any]? {

        let objectData = jsonString.data(using: .utf8)
        var dict: [String:Any]?

        if objectData != nil {
            do {
                dict = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: objectData!, options:  .allowFragments) as? [String : Any]

            } catch {
                print("Error occured.")
            }
        }
        return dict
    }
```

Once the dictionary is created you can use access the value via the key.

Comment: i dont know objective c

Comment: but how do i parse the data inside desc?

Comment: @DurnKurvirck is desc string type or dictionary type? Also, there is multiple "desc" key in your response. Which one are you referring to? Value of "desc": {
  "questions" : [
    {
      "b" : 2,
      "a" : 1
    },
    {
      "b" : 3,
      "a" : 2
    }, 

OR 

this one: "desc": asdasdasdsa ??

Comment: the one i have provided above is the response

Comment: i want to get the value of desc

Comment: which one? There are two "desc" in the response. 1. "desc": { "questions" : [ { "b" : 2, "a" : 1 }, { "b" : 3, "a" : 2 }, OR  2. "desc": asdasdasdsa ??

Comment: the asdasdasdsa should be string. It should come in quotes like "asdasdasdsa"

Comment: "desc": {
  "questions" : [
    {
      "b" : 2,
      "a" : 1
    },
    {
      "b" : 3,
      "a" : 2
    },
    {
      "b" : 2,
      "a" : 8
    },
    {
      "b" : 9,
      "a" : 7
    },
    {
      "b" : 3,
      "a" : 6
    }
  ],